# laravel 5 authentication from controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I was doing authentication in routes.php, which is not a correct way. 
Now i am doing authentication in `UserController`. I am facing a problem.

In `routes.php` i was doing this below way.

```
Route::post('/login',function(){
    $cred = Input::only('username','password');
    if(Auth::attempt($cred)){
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }else{
        $error = "Username or password is incorrect.";
       return Redirect::to('login', compact('error'));
    }
});

Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth', function(){
    return view('index');
}]);
```

Now i am using a controller `UserController`.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      Route::post('/login',function(){
        $cred = Input::only('username','password');
        if(Auth::attempt($cred)){
          return Redirect::intended('/');
        }else{
          $error = "Username or password is incorrect.";
        }
     });
    }
```

And now in `routes.php` :

```
Route::get('index', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
```

But the following code throws an error :

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about doing it like this in your route.

```
Route::post('/login', ['uses' => 'UserController@index']);
```

and in your controller you do the validation.

```
 public function index()
    {
        $cred = Input::only('username','password');
        if(Auth::attempt($cred)){
          return Redirect::intended('/');
        }else{
          $error = "Username or password is incorrect.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer now this error came up `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found
`.

Comment: You need to import Auth class.